# How to use the scanner with Wia in Asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wia

i downloaded interop.wia.dll but i don't know how to use it.Click on the button on the Default.aspx page to run the scanner and scanned document must be visible on the website.

Sorry my english is so bad,i can only explain this much.
Please,help me

Comment: I guess you are in for a disappointment: ASP.NET is running server side, so there is little chance to interact with a client side device like your scanner.

Comment: It made me sad.What am I supposed to do?

Comment: If you cannot switch to a Windows application and need to stick with your web application, your only chance will be to embed a SilverLight app into your web page to bridge the gap between client and server. However SilverLight is a slowly dying technology and the security implications to interact with client devices are complicated and full of pitfalls. I'd recommend to create a Windows app to handle the scanning and provide a web service on your ASP.NET end, but this is really only my personal preference.

Comment: There are some SDKs available that you can check out, such as [Kofax WebCapture](http://www.kofax.com/web-capture), [Scanner.js](https://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/direct-to-server-php-asp.net-overview.html) or [Dynamsoft](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN-with-HTML5-WebSocket-for-chrome.aspx) - just to name a few. Yet, they all charge you with a lot of money, plus if you need to do high volume scanning, you should probably go for a client as recommended by @Filburt.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.Have a nice day @Filburt

Comment: Yes,i tried Dynamsoft but paid.i'll try scanner.js,thanks for your suggestions :) @redlynx82